# HTML5 Audio Element styling weirdness

Tags: html, css, audio

I'm currently working on a shop website with a Windows98 theme and on the product's page I need to show a preview of audio. So far, my CSS for the HTML5 audio goes like this:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel, video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    background-color: silver;
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}

audio {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    background-color: silver;
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And that achieves this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JINbl.png
Although that works well, there's weird outlines on the edges of the audio element and I have no clue how i'd remove them (Look on the far right and left of the player, they are fairly faint). 
I don't believe using a messy JS is necessary either but would there be  a way I could possibly mask over this as it looks terrible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found a fix.
I used

```css
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 96% 5%, 100% 43%, 98% 79%, 96% 100%, 4% 100%, 2% 77%, 0% 43%, 3% 3%);
```

on the `style` tag and that has seemed to work. (Make sure it's on the style element or it won't work) That is my solution anyway, let me know if you have a better one.